# <image> in SVG: static image is visible, but dynamic is not

Tags: javascript, image, svg, raster

I have two monkeys in my code: first one is static (written in SVG tag) and it's ok, but second one (generated with JS) isn't visible, although code of both in  tag are quite the same after running. How is it possible? How can I fix it?

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <image xlink:href="http://6962mnpm.blox.pl/resource/118392wtf.jpg"
    height="250px" width="250px" x="100px"></image>

</svg>

<script>
    var test = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
    test.setAttribute("xlink:href",
        "http://6962mnpm.blox.pl/resource/118392wtf.jpg");
    test.setAttribute("height", "250px");
    test.setAttribute("width", "250px");
    test.setAttribute("x", "400px");
    document.querySelector("svg").appendChild(test);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `setAttribute` to add a namespaced attribute, even though it looks right in an inspector. Instead use setAttributeNS, as:

```
setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href','http://6962mnpm.blox.pl/resource/118392wtf.jpg');
```

Now the monkey should render properly.

```
var SVGDaddy = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var TESTOBRAZKA = document.createElementNS(SVGDaddy, "image");
with(TESTOBRAZKA) {
    setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href','http://6962mnpm.blox.pl/resource/118392wtf.jpg');
    setAttribute("height", "250px");
    setAttribute("width", "250px");
    setAttribute("x", "100px");
}
document.querySelector("svg").appendChild(TESTOBRAZKA);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/kGy5d/

Answer (score 1):

The `href` attribute has the `xlink` namespace, so you can't just use `setAttribute()`. You have to use `setAttibuteNS()`.  Try this instead:

```
setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href",
               "http://6962mnpm.blox.pl/resource/118392wtf.jpg");
```